# Import CSV to QGIS 3 where the geometry is in GeoJSON format

Tags: geojson, qgis-3, import, pgadmin-4

I have a CSV file with different attributes for each polygon. One of the attributes (column name) is GeoJSON which hold the geometry. For example, in the first polygon the geojson attribute is:

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[35.1919984817505,32.58075753670527],[35.19470214843751,32.58319843158036],[35.19618272781373,32.58186046725293],[35.19124746322633,32.57771084505097],[35.19030332565308,32.57938337350581],[35.1919984817505,32.58075753670527]]]]}
```

I was able to import the CSV file only as a table to QGIS 3. Is there a way to tell QGIS (or possibly via pg admin 4), that the attribute GeoJSON holds the geometry but in a GeoJSON format?

Comment: The GDAL CSV driver may be able to handle that https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html.